# How to interrupt an I/O call in a perl thread?

Tags: multithreading, perl, io

Looks like times of old good alarm() call are over, so how to interrupt blocking read()'s and write()'s made from perl thread (using that brand new 'threads' module) assuming the code making those blocking calls cannot be changed? Actual problem is stucking communication with Modbus device so I've created a simple testcase not to dip you into RS-485 hell:

```
use threads;
use IO::Handle;
threads->create(sub {
        $io = IO::Handle->new_from_fd(fileno(STDIN), 'r') or die;
        $br = read $io, $buf, 100;
        warn "read: $br";
});
while(1) {threads->yield()};
```

Here, warn() is never executed unless you hit Ctrl-D on keyboard. Is there any simple solution to timeout that read() call?

Comment: Have you tried to send a benign signal to the process? SIGCONT?

Comment: According to documentation, threads->kill() doesn't actually send any OS signals, and a real OS signal to PID may be caugth by ANY thread which is not blocking it (not saying about perl thread may not actually appear as OS thread at all) which makes signaling by PID a very unreliable method of interruption. Imagine two threads got stucked at the same time. Killing PID with SIGCONT will unblock just one of them (in the best case).

Comment: But you didn't actually try it?

Comment: BTW, perl does have access to the kernels select(2), doesn't it? Maybe you can use waiting with the select in the thread, instead of waiting with using read?

Comment: Just tried. kill -ALRM interrupts main thread (which is threads->yield()'ing) and terminates the whole process, adding local $SIG{ALRM}='IGNORE' makes app not to react on kill -ALRM at all. I'm sure I can achieve an interruption in a single thread using sigaction() and making all other threads ignore the same signal, but it is impossible to interrupt two simultaneously blocked read()'s this way.

Comment: [IO::Select](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Select)

Comment: You can use 4-args select for setting timeouts. perldoc -f select

Comment: Unfortunately it's not me waiting in read()... It's someone else's XS code and I don't like an idea of correcting it and recompiling it (especially considering that the final destination of the script is an ARM SBC). All I do is $someblackbox->execute(), and I want to interrupt some I/O stucked inside that black box and return an execution to my thread. If I don't find any solution I'll have to fall back to killing the whole thread which will cause loss of some statistical data and which is ugly anyway, so still searching for an acceptable solution ;)

Comment: Maybe you can proxy the channel through something you can control? Like move the "blackbox" in a process of its own, and leave the rest of the program in a controllable space, where you can do anything? Just interrupting it might not have the desired effect: if the read terminates with an EINTR, the "blackbox" might decide to explode...

Comment: @fork0 Thanks, it's still a better solution than killing the whole thread... Although I was hoping for something like threads_alarm(10)/threads_alarm(0) like in the good old times when server codebases were small ;)

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you trying to interrupt a perl read() (as the example shows) or some XS read() (as you say in comments).  Does "return an execution to my thread [sic]" mean throw an exception or continue execution?

Comment: I'm trying to interrupt IO::Termios->read, which is actually IO::Handle->read, implemented via perl read(), which results in read() syscall anyway (on Linux systems at least). What I'm trying to do is to reproduce the alarm() behavior when process gets a signal and read() stops blocking and results in EINTR.

Comment: @DmitrySinyavin, that's alarm() behavior in C without SA_RESTART.  :)  Perl, on the other hand, implements SA_RESTART-esque behavior for most syscalls, which is why you sometimes see a `$SIG{ALRM} = sub { die ...; }; eval { alarm ...; some_blocking_call(); alarm 0; }` approach, to ham-fistedly avoid the restart.  Your inherited code and constraints aren't easy.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than threading (which is ill-supported in Perl at best, and mostly frowned upon), why not try one of the event modules instead? That's the standard solution to concurrency in Perl.

Comment: I'm not the author of the original code though I understand why threaded model were implemented instead of event-driven in that case. Threads are dedicated to making requests to several devices which differ so much you cannot even create a common superclass for them, every device requires its own processing and flow control. Tasks performed by threads are spread from initializing and driving GPIO pins through low-level kernel driver and to waiting for USB connection and initializing some weird pieces of hardware. Honestly, I don't understand why Perl was chosen for that project ;))